# integral of equivalent functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have two distribution functions $F(x)=1-e^{-\mu (x-\alpha)}-e^{-\lambda x}$ and $\tilde{F}(x)=1-e^{-\mu (x-\alpha)}$ ($\mu < \lambda $), I know they are equivalent by using the relation $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac {1-F(x)} {1-\tilde{F}(x)} \sim 1 $. My question,  is how to prove the following integrals are equivalent.
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \left[1-e^{-\mu (x-\alpha)}-e^{-\lambda x}\right]^n \zeta e^{-\zeta \alpha} d\alpha \sim \int_{0}^{\infty} \left[1-e^{-\mu (x-\alpha)}\right]^n \zeta e^{-\zeta \alpha} d\alpha
$$

I was thinking of unifrom integrability but wasnt sure how to approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have a dependence of both $\zeta$ and $n$ in both integrals. With respect to which of these you want those two expressions to be related via $\sim$?

Comment: @dennis_s I edited the question. I am integrating over $\alpha$  (my mistake). So I want the two integrals to be equivalent in terms of $\alpha$

Comment: I still don't understand. You can factor out both $F^n(x)$ and $\tilde{F^n}(x)$ on either side, and since both remaining integrals are equal they cancel out. Also $\alpha$ doesn't appear on either side. After integrating there is no $\alpha$ left.

Comment: @dennis_s, so I figured out there is a missing term in the equation. Actually $F(x)$ has $\alpha$ terms on it (see the edited equation). So I  can't just take $F(x)$ as common factor.

Comment: Now you cannot factor out anything but $\zeta$, that's true. Then the expressions on both sides are depending on $x$, $\zeta$ and $n$ after integration. I am assuming that these are supposed to be equivalent w.r.t. $x$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$. But should these be uniform w.r.t. both $n$ and $\zeta$ or pointwise?